# VSCode - Hide TypeScript interfaces/types feature?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

When I'm just glancing through my code, I don't need to see all of my type and interface declarations, or the type definitions

```
const sometext: string = "blahblah"
```

***string*** being what I mean by definitions. I don't know the proper term.

I understand the importance of being able to view this information, but it's not always needed and can make it more confusing to skim through code with all the clutter.

I'd like to be able to use a hotkey to hide/show all TypeScript-related stuff in my code, so I can focus on the pure JS when needed.

I found [this GitHub post](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/36823) suggesting the same idea, but they just shot down the idea.

I just want to be able to quickly fold/unfold all types/interfaces, and being able to hide (or discolor) the *definitions* would be nice too. It can be helpful when the code is fresh in your mind, and you name your variables well. Being able to flip between typing and just viewing the JS logic would be nice.

Is there a plugin/feature that accomplishes this?

Comment: You could add a lint rule to remove unnecessary type annotations. https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/295

Comment: I think they just want it to be hidden in the ide, not actually remove them from the source code.

Comment: I'd stick with the built inlay hints. You write a code without type annotations and you just turn on/off inlay hints when necessary. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tY4mrgW3jcM

Comment: @NicholasTower that is correct. This is purely cosmetic

Answer (score 0):

This folds types based on the TypeScript AST:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SuncappedGames.typescript-fold

The technique is forked from another repo.  It uses textDecoration to just hide the text.

[image]